# How threads should verifiy that the queue is full while it's being modified at the same time by another thread?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, queue, synchronization, openmp

I asked a question yesterday on the site and received an answer on the source of my error but I am still confused on how to solve the problem.
So I'm trying to replace a synchronization barrier with a function called by threads that have a rank other than 1. Thread number 1 is responsible for filling the queue.

I had the idea that threads (rank not equal to 1) should check if the queue is full. If it is not, they call the already predefined sleep function. If it is full, we can be sure that we can pass without fearing a race condition.

```
 if (num_thread==1) then
      do i_task=first_task,last_task
         tasklist_GRAD(i_task)%state=STATE_READY
         call queue_enqueue_data(master_queue,tasklist_GRAD(i_task))   !< add the list elements to the queue (full queue)
      end do
   end if

   if (num_thread .ne. 1) then
      call wait_thread(master_queue)
   end if

!!$       !$OMP BARRIER    !!!!!!! retired OMP BARR
   call master_worker_execution(self,var,master_queue,worker_queue,first_task,last_task,nthreads,num_thread,lck)
```

Here is the definition of the wait function:

```
subroutine wait_thread(master_queue)
    type(QUEUE_STRUCT),pointer,asynchronous::master_queue !< the master queue of tasks
    do while (.not. queue_full(master_queue)) 
       call system_sleep(1) 
    end do
  end subroutine wait_thread
```

The problem is that thread number 1 will obviously modify the queue called `master_queue` so write and at the same time the other threads will check if the queue is full and so modify it too. This can lead to a race condition.

Here is the definition of `queue_full` function:

```
recursive logical function queue_full( queue )
    type(QUEUE_STRUCT),asynchronous, intent(in)  :: queue
    !$OMP CRITICAL 
    queue_full = (queue%size == queue%capacity)
    !$OMP END CRITICAL 
  end function queue_full
```

When running I don't get a segmentation error but I don't get the results for the code with `OMP_BARRIER` either.

Usually I get values displayed but now I get a blinking cursor.

My question is: is there any way to solve this? Is it impossible to replace `OMP_BARRIER`?

I tried to add the attribute `asynchronous` for the `master_queue` so the declaration became like this :     `type(QUEUE_STRUCT),pointer,asynchronous::master_queue !< the master queue of tasks`. The `critical` directive in the definition of `queue_full` is something that I added too but in vain.

Any help, please ?

**EDIT:**
I just tried this method but I don't know if it really replaces OMP_BARRIER. Here is the new module `time` (nothing complicated, `system_sleep` and `wait` functions):

```
module time
  use QUEUE
contains
  recursive subroutine system_sleep(wait)
    use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int
    integer,intent(in) :: wait
    integer(kind=c_int):: waited
    interface
       function c_usleep(msecs) bind (C,name="usleep")
         import
         integer(c_int) :: c_usleep
         integer(c_int),intent(in),VALUE :: msecs
       end function c_usleep
    end interface
    if(wait.gt.0)then
       waited=c_usleep(int(wait,kind=c_int))
    endif
  end subroutine system_sleep

  recursive subroutine wait(full)
    logical,intent(in)::full
    do
       call system_sleep(1000)
       if (full .eqv. .true.) EXIT 
    end do
  end subroutine wait
end module time
```

and this is how I replaced `OMP_BARRIER`:

```
       full = .false. 
       first_task=5
       last_task=6

       if (num_thread==1) then
          do i_task=first_task,last_task
             tasklist_GRAD(i_task)%state=STATE_READY
             call queue_enqueue_data(master_queue,tasklist_GRAD(i_task))   !< add the list elements to the queue (full queue)
          end do
          full=.true. 
       end if

       if (num_thread .ne. 1) then      !!!!!!!!!! how to replace OMP_BARRIER
          call wait(full)    !!! wait until full equal to true 
       end if


       call master_worker_execution(self,var,master_queue,worker_queue,first_task,last_task,nthreads,num_thread,lck)
```

I want also to add that the `shared` variable `full` is of type `logical`.

Is this an efficient way to get rid of an explicit barrier ?

Comment: What form of parallelism are you using? You've tagged openmp, but on the previous question you said you wanted multiple nodes?

Comment: @veryreverie I am using OpenMP at the moment. I'm being asked to do this as part of an internship. I have to replace the `OMP_BARRIER`s and prepare the code well before going to multi-node. I have modified the question and put a solution but I don't know if it is a good solution. Can you tell me if my solution is correct and if I have replaced `OMP_BARRIER` properly?

Comment: You really need some kind of parallel framework to do parallel calculations. Your question boils down to "how do I make one thread wait for another thread". And the answer to that is to use the `barrier` equivalent from your parallel framework. Your current method won't work on multiple nodes, because `full` will be local to one node and the threads on other nodes won't be able to read it.

Comment: If you are using OpenMP and the version of the code works with OMP_BARRIER, then why are you changing the code?  _"My boss told me to remove OMP_BARRIER"_ is not a valid answer.  Are you trying to port OpenMP code to use the Message Passage Interface (MPI)?  Because, it looks like your re-implementing OpenMPI  and/os MPICH.

Comment: Why not use the OpenMP `task` directives and their respective synchronization options such `taskgroup`, `taskwait`, and task dependences?  It seems like you're re-implementing a lot of functionality that OpenMP already has and that was tuned for many years.